# pandas - assign column label to a record value as result of min/max function

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to extract the column label from which a value was selected as a result of the `min()` or `max()` function?  An example will certainly illustrate the question better than I'm wording it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Method1' : [10, 7, 3, 9, 7],
                    'Method2' : [10, 1, 5, 7, 8],
                    'Method3' : [5, 6, 2, 4, 10]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: Method1     Method2     Method3
         10           10          5
          7           1           6
          3           5           2
          9           7           4
          7           8           10
```

Now I'd like to create a new column, `BestMethod` that contains the column name of the lowest value for a record.  I know how to get the lowest value (below), but what about the column name?

```
In [4]: for i, row in df.iterrows():
              print min([r for r in row])
          5
          1
          2
          4
          7
```

So the final result would look similar to this:

```
In [5]:   df
Out[5]:   Method1   Method2     Method3     BestMethod
              10         10           5       Method3
               7          1           6       Method2
               3          5           2       Method3
               9          7           4       Method3
               7          8          10       Method1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) to get the index value of the minimum value (be sure to specify axis=1 for rows).  There is a corresponding `idxmax` as well.

```
df['BestMethod'] = df.idxmin(axis=1)

>>> df
   Method1  Method2  Method3 BestMethod
0       10       10        5    Method3
1        7        1        6    Method2
2        3        5        2    Method3
3        9        7        4    Method3
4        7        8       10    Method1
```

Comment: You're answer was spot on.  What if `df['Method4'] = 'N/A'`,  or mixed w/ some other string values?  Is it easy enough to perform the `idxmin` operation on all the columns except `Method4`?

Comment: Maybe that is a better question, and the one I should've asked, as it would depict a more realistic dataset. I'm unfamiliar with the etiquette for editing questions with accepted answers vs. asking a new question.

Comment: You would generally ask a new question.  NaN/None values are fine, but strings are problematic.  To select from a subset of columns (e.g. only Method1 and Method2): `df['BestMethod2'] = df[['Method1', 'Method2']].idxmin(axis=1)` or `df.loc[:, ['Method1', 'Method2']].idxmin(axis=1)`